# Чему эквивалентна пустая стрелочная функция?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Пустая стрелочная функция  **() => {}**  эквивалентна:

```js
function() {
  return;
}
```

или

```js
function() {}
```

Как лучше записывать стрелочную функцию, чтобы оператор **return** фактически был, но ничего не возвращал?

Comment: функция всегда возвращает значение, по умолчанию это `undefined`. Так что разницы нет ни какой между вашими примерами

Comment: @ThisMan а если мы используем промисы внутри промисов, то функция,  которая будет вызвана с результатом при resolve, обязательно должна быть с оператором `return` , как я понимаю. Например:
`return axion.post().then( r => r );`

Comment: `обязательно должна быть с оператором return` и что по вашему произойдет, если не использовать `return`?

Comment: `Promise.resolve(10).then(function(a) { console.log(a) })` можно и так написать, доступ к `then` все равно будет

Comment: `async` функция по умолчанию промис возвращает, кстати

Comment: У вас в чем именно проблема? Или чего вы хотите добиться? Возможно, вы не в ту сторону копаете

Comment: @ThisMan допустим у нас цепочка промисов, есть ли там необходимость в операторе return, если нам не нужно передавать какое-либо значение, а просто нужно последовательное выполнение? `doSomething().then(function(result) {
  return doSomethingElse(result);
})
.then(function(newResult) {
  return doThirdThing(newResult);
})`

Comment: если нужен результат `doSomething` и так далее, тогда офк нужны

Comment: `Promise.resolve(10).then(a => a + 10).then(console.log)` возвращать нужно, если нужен доступ к результату предыдущего коллбека

Comment: @ThisMan поняла, проверила, действительно никакой разницы, что с оператором, что без. Была уверена в обратном)
Спасибо!

Comment: @ThisMan оформите всё ответом)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функция всегда возвращает какой-то результат. По умолчанию для обычных функций это `undefined`, для асинхронных `Promise<undefined>`, так что какой-то принципиальной разницы между возвращать пустой `return` или не возвращать - нет.

```
(function() {})(); // undefined
(function() { return; })(); // undefined
(function() { return undefined; })(); // undefined
```

В случае с промисами, так же, если нам не нужен результат коллбека, то можно не возвращать ничего, это не сломает промис.

```
Promise.resolve(10)
  .then(function (a) { console.log(a) }) // 10
  .then(console.log); // undefined, так как предыдущий коллбек ничего не возвращает
```

Если же результат коллбека нам нужен, то тогда нужно вернуть его явно

```
Promise.resolve(10)
  .then(function(a) { return a + 10 })
  .then(console.log); // 20
```

Comment: @Drakonoved кажется в этом нет смысла и только возникнет вопрос, зачем явно `undefined` возвращается

Answer (score -1):

Если нужно чтобы функция тихо прикрылась: 
function() { return null }